# Teradata Current year and year-1

Tags: sql, teradata

How to get the dynamic years in the Query for where condition, i need to fetch data for 2017,2018,2019, currently i am hard coding them ( where FSC_YR in (2017,2018,2019) instead i need in a dynamic way. How to do it in teradata.
I tried extract(year from current_date)-2,extract(year from current_date)-1,extract(year from current_date)-3). I am getting error too many expression.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking for a range of year numbers, why not just use a BETWEEN?

```
SELECT * 
FROM data
WHERE fsc_yr BETWEEN EXTRACT(year FROM current_date - interval '2' year) AND EXTRACT(year FROM current_date)
```

But as @dnoeth pointed out in the comments.
To avoid an error when running it on Feb. 29, using INTERVAL might not be the safest method.

But just subtracting from the year number isn't so bad really.

```
SELECT * 
FROM data
WHERE fsc_yr BETWEEN EXTRACT(year FROM current_date)-2 AND EXTRACT(year FROM current_date)
```

Also note that such error can come from selecting more than 1 column in the query for an `IN`

For example this would fail:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE Col1 IN (SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Tabel2)
```

So if you would use the query for data with a `*` then it would still result in that error.

Comment: You better switch to `ADD_MONTHS(current_date, -2*12)`instead of Interval-calculatuion (will fail at a leap day, '2020-02-29`)

Comment: Hmm, can't test it on a TeraData atm, but what date does this give?: `select DATE '2020-02-29' - INTERVAL '2' YEAR as dt`

Comment: It doesn't return a data but an *Invalid date* error (that stupid Standard SQL calculation returns `2018-02-29` which obviously doesn't exists).

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for the insightfull help. :)  Since it's just to calculate a previous year subtracting a number seems the best option.

Comment: Other DBMSes don't follow Standard SQL :-) And your new calculation is much easier indeed.